# From getExternalStorageDirectory to internal storage

Tags: java, android, eclipse, storage

again I need a little help from you. I have this code for simple photo app, but this code save edited image on SD card, but I want change this to save image on internal memory of phone.

```
private File captureImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutputStream output;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll1.getWidth(), ll1.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    /*
     * bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, ll1.getWidth(),
     * ll1.getHeight());
     */
    Canvas b = new Canvas(bitmap);
    ll1.draw(b);

    // Find the SD Card path
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/background_eraser/");
    dir.mkdirs();

    mImagename = "image" + cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".png";

    // Create a name for the saved image
    file = new File(dir, mImagename);

    // Show a toast message on successful save
    Toast.makeText(SelectedImgActivity.this, "Image Saved to SD Card",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;

}
```

Any suggestions how to do this? I think I must change only Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory to something other, but what?

Thank you!

Edited:

I was change this line to `File filepath = Environment.getDataDirectory(); and I think this works. But this make new folder in root folder...I want it in pictures... How to archive this?`

Edited 2:

Now I was edited code to this

```
private File captureImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutputStream output;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll1.getWidth(), ll1.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    /*
     * bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, ll1.getWidth(),
     * ll1.getHeight());
     */
    Canvas b = new Canvas(bitmap);
    ll1.draw(b);

    // Find the SD Card path
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
//  File filepath = Environment.getDataDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Background Remover/");

    dir.mkdirs();

    mImagename = "image" + cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".png";

    // Create a name for the saved image
    file = new File(dir, mImagename);

    // Show a toast message on successful save
    Toast.makeText(SelectedImgActivity.this, "Image Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;

}
```

Everything works fine, except Toast show...

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/background_eraser/");
```

With:

```
File dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "background_eraser";
```

You can use:

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
```

> Added in API level 1
>
> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.